# WEBGL addressables lags

Tags: multithreading, unity-game-engine, webgl, addressables

The problem is that the packages are loaded in the same stream as the game and when they are unpacked, the game freezes. Is it possible to fix it somehow?

```
AsyncOperationHandle downloadAsync = Addressables.DownloadDependenciesAsync(_preloadAssets[i]);

while (!downloadAsync.IsDone && downloadAsync.IsValid())
{
  downloadStatus = downloadAsync.GetDownloadStatus();
  OnPercentChange.Invoke(downloadStatus.Percent);
  await Task.Yield();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean WebGL build? you added webgl tag...

Comment: Yes webgl build